# Which File to load from National Hydrography Dataset?

Tags: qgis, raster, file-geodatabase, hydrography

I'm using QGIS 2.0 on MacBook with OS X 10.8.5.
I downloaded a National Hydrography Database file. Unzipped, it is titled NHD11032_NM.gdb.
I try to add the layer as a vector file, and all the sub-files (nomenclature/terminology?) are ghosted, so I try adding the layer as a raster. All the files are visible and available.

Which of the dozens of files do I add to bring the file into my QGIS project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid you are lost with QGIS. According to the Readme.doc, the data is in Arcgis 9.3 format.

QGIS and GDAL only support gdb file databases written by Arcgis 10 and above.

As an alternative, you can download the data from [NHD Plus](http://www.horizon-systems.com/NHDPlus/NHDPlusV2_data.php) in other formats too. These are shapefiles and Arcinfo hdr raster files, depending on the topic. Both formats can be read by QGIS.